# errors while using 'sudo apt-get update'

Tags: apt, updates, wine, sudo

```
W: Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 13.10 _Saucy Salamander_ - Release amd64 (20131016.1)/dists/saucy/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I am new to ubuntu so I dont know how to solve this error. This is shown at the end after executing 'sudo apt-get update' command. I think this is preventing me from installing new apps like `wine 1.7`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not preventing you to install wine.Just try to remove or put # before the below line in `/etc/apt/sources.list` file,

```
deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 13.10 Saucy Salamander - Release amd64 (20131016.1)]/ saucy main restricted
```

And then run an update,

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: is sources.list.save same as sources.list?

Comment: no.To delete the line run `sudo nautilus` command.From that move to `/etc/apt/sources.list` file and then open it.Now delete or add # before that line.

Comment: i think i may have accidently removed that file. What to do??

Comment: Don't worry run this command, `sudo cp /etc/apt/sources.list.save /etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: the above line is not there. Instead there is deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 13.10 _Saucy Salamander_ - Release amd64 (20131016.1)]/ saucy main restricted

Comment: Now run `sudo apt-get update` if you got any error then post back it.

Comment: Still showing the same error.

Comment: yes the same line.Put # before that line and save it.